# Salesforce OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow id_token

Tags: oauth2, jwt

According to this [guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0) id_token should be in the response if scope parameter contains openid, however the same guide says that scope parameter is not supported.

As I've verified no id_token issued with this flow, even if I had set openid scope in Connected Application configuration. If I put request parameter scope, token endpoint throws an error that scope parameter is not supported for this flow, same as guide says.

Is it documentation error or am I missing something? Is it really impossible to get id_token from Salesforce in headless flows, where user(human) is not involved (user-agent and web-server flows require user interactions)?

Comment: I haven't tried to do this for myself yet. Did you wait long enough for your Connected App to re-do whatever it is that it needs to do when you change the configuration? Do you have "Users may self-authorize" set, or is it "Admin-approved users are pre-authorized"? Have you successfully gotten an access token for the user you're using before? Have you included "openId" in the scope header of the request as well as had "openId" configured in the connected app? Have you authenticated your target user with a different flow _after_ adding "openId" to the scope of your connected app?